# Swift 3: Accessing nested dictionary from returns nil?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3

I'm having a problem trying to access a nested `Dictionary`, which seems to return `nil`.

Here's the output my `info` of type `Dictionary<String, Any>`:

```
info = ["list_order": 1, "name": Some Text, "id": 1, "menu_items": {
    1 =     {
        "food_name" = "String";
        "food_picture" = "link";
        "food_price" = "2.00";
    };
    2 =     {
        "food_name" = "String";
        "food_picture" = "link";
        "food_price" = "5.00";
        id = 2;
    };
}]
```

The output of `info["menu_items"]`:

```
info["menu_items"] = {
    1 =     {
        "food_name" = "String";
        "food_picture" = "link";
        "food_price" = "2.00";
        id = 1;
    };
    2 =     {
        "food_name" = "String";
        "food_picture" = "link";
        "food_price" = "5.00";
        id = 2;
    };
}
```

However, the following assigning produces a `nil` in `test`:

```
let test = info["menu_items"] as? Dictionary<Int, Any>
```

Is there something not obvious or am I not understanding basic fundamentals?

Comment: Why are you using dictionaries to store data with static keys?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: I need to reference it later in the code to put into `UITableView`

Comment: And that can't just be done with structs or objects?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: I can store it as a struct, but is there any benefits in using it vs the way I currently am?...

Comment: Of course there is. Structs are type safe, and let you avoid this mess of force casts and optionals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your key is not `Int` type then most probably it is of `String` type, try once using `[String: Any]`.

```
if let menuItems = info["menu_items"] as? [String: Any] {
     print(menuItems)
}
```

Comment: Wow, so right!...I'm an idiot!...why though, does calling `print` on `info["menu_items"]` show the key without quotes?...this confuses me in thinking it's an int

Comment: @Pangu It is batter if you use check actual JSON using `Postman` or `RestAPI` and check that JSON on online editor will give you batter understanding of your `JSON` instead of checking output in Xcode.